# Confusion about Weinberg's short argument for the existence of antiparticles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, charge, antimatter

In section 5.1 of Weinberg's *The Quantum Theory of Fields Volume I*, there is a short argument for the existence of antiparticles:

> It may be that the particles that are destroyed and created by these fields carry non-zero values of one or more conserved quantum numbers like the electric charge. For instance, if particles of species $n$ carry a value $q(n)$ for the electric charge $Q$, then
> $$[Q,a(\mathbf{p},\sigma,n)]=-q(n)a(\mathbf{p},\sigma,n),$$
> $$[Q,a^\dagger(\mathbf{p},\sigma,n)]=q(n)a^\dagger(\mathbf{p},\sigma,n).$$
> In order that $\mathscr{H}(x)$ should commute with the charge operator $Q$ (or some other symmetry generator) it is necessary that it be formed out of fields that have simple commutation relations with $Q$:
> $$[Q,\psi_\ell(x)]=-q_\ell\psi_\ell(x)$$
> for then we can make $\mathscr{H}(x)$ commute with $Q$ by constructing it as a sum of products of fields $\psi_{\ell_1}\psi_{\ell_2}\cdots$ and adjoints $\psi_{m_1}^\dagger \psi_{m_2}^\dagger\cdots$ such that
> $$q_{\ell_1}+q_{\ell_2}+\cdots - q_{m_1} - q_{m_2}-\cdots =0.$$
> Now, Eq. (5.1.33) is satisfied for one particular component $\psi^+_\ell(x)$ of the
> annihilation field if and only if all particle species $n$ that are destroyed
> by the field carry the same charge $q(n) = q_\ell$, and it is satisfied for one
> particular component $\psi^-_\ell(x)$ of the creation field if and only if all particle
> species $\bar{n}$ that are created by the field carry the charge $q(\bar{n}) = -q_\ell$. **We
> see that in order for such a theory to conserve quantum numbers like
> electric charge, there must be a doubling of particle species carrying non-zero values of such quantum numbers:** if a particular component of the
> annihilation field destroys a particle of species $n$, then the same component
> of the creation field must create particles of a species $\bar{n}$, known as the
> antiparticles of the particles of species n, which have opposite values of
> all conserved quantum numbers. *This is the reason for antiparticles.*

The issue is that I don't immediately see how we reach the conclusion I've highlighted in bold from the statements above. In particular, it seems to me that it could be the case that the field operator is an expansion in annihilation operators for a single species of particle alone (making its conjugate an expansion in the corresponding creation operators alone) and the commutator $[Q,\mathscr{H}(x)]$ could still be zero.

Comment: Immediately preceding the quote you've given, Weinberg claims that one must take a linear combination of a creation and annihilation operators if one wants the fields to be causal (in the sense of Eq. (5.1.32)) which in turn insures Lorentz invariance of the whole theory as discussed at the end of section 3.1.